# Error Installing mopa/composer-bridge using Composer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I am trying to integrate Twitter Bootstrap with my Symfony2 project using the MopaBootstrapBundle, and I am using composer to manage my vendor libraries.

The initial problem that I had was that the mopa/bootstrap-bundle requires the composer-bridge, so I followed the instructions here https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/issues/345

However I still get the following message in my logs

- Installing mopa/composer-bridge (dev-master master)
  Cloning master

  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone http://github.com/phiamo/mopacomposerbridge.git via git, https and http protocols, aborting.
- git://github.com/phiamo/mopacomposerbridge.git
  fatal: remote error:
    Repository not found.
- https://github.com/phiamo/mopacomposerbridge.git
  fatal: Authentication failed
- http://github.com/phiamo/mopacomposerbridge.git
  fatal: Authentication failed

I have tried changing the minimum stability to dev with no success, however I can access the files via my browser but not via command line, and other packages have been installed.

UPDATE: The complete composer.json below

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
    "twitter/bootstrap": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "*",
    "craue/formflow-bundle": "dev-master",
    "jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
            {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "mopa/composer-bridge",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/phiamo/mopacomposerbridge.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/phiamo/mopacomposerbridge/zipball/master",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        },
       {
           "type":"package",
           "package": {
               "version":"dev-master",
               "name":"jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap",
               "source": {
                   "url":"https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap.git",
                   "type":"git",
                   "reference":"master"
               },
               "dist": {
                   "url":"https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap/archive/master",
                   "type":"zip"
               }
           }
       }
   ],
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web"
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you provide the full composer.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about 6 to 8 hours of battling with different combinations, it suddenly just worked, so I suspect that this may have been caused by an issue with connecting to Github from my box or something of the sort, but it works fine without any problems

Comment: Yes, as the error messages suggest, this is a problem in the transport layer, not the code. E.g. the repo was down. Please accept your answer to mark this question as solved.